# Java method contains another method throws exception

Tags: java

Inside Method A, there is method B. Method B throws exception, but method A compiled even it does not catch exception or throws exception, could it be possible?

Method B is something like as below:

```
MethodB() throws SomeException{
   if(Some)
        doneSomething
        return
   else if(some)
        donesomethingElse
        return 
   throw SomeException  
}
```

Comment: Yes, `SomeException` is a subclass of `RuntimeException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `SomeException` extends [`RuntimeException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html). Then you don't need to catch it even if the signature looks like that.

Also note that you can just remove the `throws SomeException` in that case. Read more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are some unchecked exception, who might not be caught / rethrown.

Look at this tutorial - [Unchecked Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html).

Answer (score 0):

Even if `SomeException` is a checked exception, this can happen due to separate compilation.

Suppose you write a class:

```
public class B {
  public static void foo() {
  }
}
```

Then a class that calls it:

```
public class A {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    B.foo();
  }
}
```

Then say:

```
javac A.java
java A
```

All is fine. Now change B:

```
public class B {
  public static void foo() throws java.io.IOException {
    throw new java.io.IOException();
  }
}
```

And this time just compile B before running:

```
javac B.java
java A
```

You get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException
    at B.foo(B.java:4)
    at A.main(A.java:4)
```

In the real world this happens when individual .jar files are updated after they've been modified by maintainers who don't understand the problems caused by adding more `throws` clauses.