# Java Not Catching Exception

Tags: java, logging, exception, stack-trace, java1.4

Unfortunately, I don't have control over `getUserByUserId(String)`.  The way it behaves is to return a User if a user if found and to throw a `OntNoObjectExistsException` if no user is found.  My problem is that for some reason, the catch doesn't catch `OntNoObjectExistsException` when it gets thrown.

The type hierarchy for this exception is: `OntNoObjectExistsException` -> `OntException` -> `Exception` -> `Throwable`.

```
public boolean isUserIdAvailable(String userId) {
    try {
        return super.getUserByUserId(userId) == null;
    } catch (OntNoObjectExistsException e){
        return true;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        appLog.error(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return false;
}
```

I tried this code to test the waters and the problem persisted.  Note, I'm catching `Throwable`.

```
public boolean isUserIdAvailable(String userId) {
    try {
        return super.getUserByUserId(userId) == null;
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        appLog.error(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Here's the stacktrace:**

```
com.opennetwork.exception.OntNoObjectExistsException: User not found
    at com.bcbst.dsmart.api.WebUser.getUserByUserId(WebUser.java:411)
    at com.bcbst.dsmart.api.WebProspectiveMemberBean.isUserIdAvailable(WebProspectiveMemberBean.java:71)
    at com.bcbst.dsmart.api.EJSLocalStatelessWebProspectiveMember_ce00ef7b.isUserIdAvailable(EJSLocalStatelessWebProspectiveMember_ce00ef7b.java:120)
    at com.bcbst.prospectivememberweb.actions.UsageagreementAction.execute(UsageagreementAction.java:61)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:525)
```

Also note, this is java 1.4. Something else I can't control right now.

Comment: Whats the full package name of the imported exception in your WebUser class?

Comment: Are you using the correct type? Should catch `Exception` otherwise.

Comment: Check you only have one OntNoObjectExistsException and that it is the one you are catching.

Comment: FWIW, I tried reducing to a single catch catching Throwable, and the problem persisted.

Comment: @dharga That's quite significant, make sure you edit your question to highlight that clearly.

Comment: Nambari: it isn't catching there either (as per the st). I even tried catching Throwable instead...as a hail Mary

Comment: First of all, on what evidence are you not catching this exception? You must convince us, as well as yourself, beyond any doubt. You **are** catching it **somewhere**, where exatly are you catching it?

Comment: I've confirmed the type is the same, I've checked the fully qualified names in both classes, they match.

Comment: @Marko: The stack trace is pretty clear that it's blowing right by without catching it here.  This function should return true/false and not throw anything.

Comment: Isn't `OntNoObjectExistsException` by any chance a subclass of `RuntimeException` ?

Comment: @Less Doesn't explain why it wasn't caught by a `Throwable` clause.

Comment: No, dharga, there you'd be completely wrong. The stack trace proves that the exception is indeed **thrown**, which you already know.

Comment: @Duncan Jones Yes, you're right

Comment: what? if it was caught, then the trace wouldn't extend from getUserByUserId all the way down into the struts layer and beyond.  Unless if I was rethrowing it here or something, but I'm clearly not doing that.

Comment: You don't get the basic concept of a stack trace, then. Your method was **called** by the struts layer, of course the trace documents that. If your beloved `getUserByUserId` logged the exception as well as throwing it, **this is exactly what you are expected to see**.

Comment: The question is about it being caught. So, if it was caught, then it wouldn't stack trace like this and would simply return true/false.  Unless of course, I threw it again, but as you can see, I'm not doing that.  But we don't see that, the stack trace tells me it wasn't caught and percolated right back up to the ThreadPool$Worker.run...ergo, uncaught anywhere in user code.

Comment: Whatever your problem is, it's not evident from the code you've posted. Did you check against the line numbers in the stack trace to make sure it's being thrown from where you think it is?

Comment: @JordanBentley: yes, that was one of the first things I checked. Firstly to make sure it was running the correct version of the app and to make sure it was happening exactly where I thought it was happening.

Comment: Just to make sure: are you 100% positive that the exception is related to _that_ piece of code? What's the fully qualified class name, to whom the method `isUserIdAvailable(String userId)` belongs? -- Sorry, already asked by @JordanBentley, and answered to inbetween...

Comment: @AlainSaint-Etienne: Yes, I'm also sure about the FQCN and it is happening here, in addition to line numbers matching.

Comment: @dharga maybe throw a printline in there to make sure it's properly rebuilding the class? If everything is happening like you think it is your result should be impossible as far as I can tell.

Comment: dharga, you are making less sense every minute. Do you honestly believe the stacktrace of an exception **depends on the place where you catch it**? That is ridiculous. The stacktrace **is created at the moment of throwing** and it **never changes afterwards**. Wherever it is printed out, **it will show the same thing**.

Comment: Can you post the class definition for `OntNoObjectExistsException`?

Comment: Related to what @MarkoTopolnik said, are you sure that this output isn't coming from the logger? Is there anything else in the output other than that stack trace?

Comment: Can you briefly explain what are these two classes with method `isUserIdAvailable()` showing in the stack, and which one your code belongs to? Can you also confirm your class inherits com.bcbst.dsmart.api.WebUser? Directly or not?

Comment: OK, answering myself about the 2-classes issue: you seem to be working on an EJB method. Therefore, your class WebProspectiveMemberBean most certainly directly extends WebUser.  Did you double-check everything is consistent on the client side (interface definition, etc..), i.e. the (generated?) EJSLocalStatelessWebProspectiveMember_ce00ef7b class?

Comment: Got it.  @Marko, I credit you for the find.  After a lot of searching, I found the source for getUserByUserId, the stacktrace printout is happening there. it's just catching, printing, rethrowing...why? who knows.  You were right. I was under the assumption that it wasn't being caught because the app is throwing a 500 somewhere.  Since I saw the stacktrace, I assumed (fail) that it was the problem.  With a few print statements, I can see that trace if printed before the function returns.  So, now the joy of finding this silent 500.  Ugh!  I hate working on someone else's app.

Comment: fwiw, idk what I was smoking..i'm reading what I said earlier, and yeah...i was hungry for lunch or something, lol. thanks for working through this with me.

Comment: I've seen a lot of such code in the apps I've worked with, especially when checked exceptions are involved. People are forced to catch them, but have no idea what to do with them, and then "just to be safe" they catch, log, and rethrow. Then the next layer repeats the same, and you get a whole lotta mess in your log.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: agreed, I hate this app.  sadly, I have to patch it.  yay for "do what you're told and shut up"...ugh, fml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me propose a hypothesis. `WebUser.getUserByUserId` contains this code:

```
if (userNotFoundCondition) {
  OntNoObjectExistsException e = new OntNoObjectExistsException("User not found");
  logger.error("User not found", e);
  throw e;
}
```

This hypothesis is 100% consistent with all the evidence you submitted. In order to move forward with your investigation, you must first disprove this hypothesis.

Comment: close enough.  after the throw, it's caught, e.printStackTrace() and then rethrown.  for your help, i'm picking this answer.

Comment: @dharga If it was rethrown it must be caught by the subclass code.

Comment: That exceeds even my imagination. The guy who wrote apparently wasn't aware that you can instantiate an exception without immediately throwing it.

Comment: I was well aware, however simply didn't think of it.  hence why I credit you for the solution cause you were the one that suggested I think of it.

Comment: No, I mean why he wrote `try {throw new OntNoObjectExistsException();} catch (OntNoObjectExistsException e) { e.printStacktrace(); throw e;}`  when he could simply have said `OntNoObjectExistsException e = new OntNoObjectExistsException(); e.printStacktrace(); throw e;`.

Answer (score 1):

You are catching exception in the superclass where you throw new `Throwable`.

Comment: Can you expand on this answer a little?

Comment: @Duncan What to explain, look at the stacktrace where the exception is thrown. And it probably `RuntimeException` rethrown or stacktrace from there.

Comment: I don't think there was any doubt that the superclass method was throwing the exception. The issue is about why the OP cannot catch the exception. Your last comment about rethrown RuntimeException is interesting.

Comment: This is from JavaDoc: `A method is not required to declare in its throws clause any subclasses of RuntimeException that might be thrown during the execution of the method but not caught.`

Comment: It's not a subclass of RuntimeException. I posted the type hierarchy.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yes, if you mean catchable, but is uncaught by the OP 's code above.

Comment: I mean "checked", it is an official term. `Throwable` must be declared to be thrown, just like any other checked exception. But all this is beside the point really, since it is quite obvious that `Throwable` is not in fact the type of exception being thrown. It is `OntNoObjectExistsException`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik you doesn't state that in your answer nor OP. Beside the point OP state is not able catch throwable in last edit, hence the code not reached at all.

Comment: Did you see the stacktrace? It clearly says `OntNoObjectExistsException`. Do you have an alternative explanation on how that exception type came up?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I already explained it in the answer and comments, but seams the flow is disregard it at the end.

Comment: I have read your answer and all the comments below it once again. Nowhere in sight is any explanation as to how the `OntNoObjectExistsException` came about, but I see plenty of claims that `new Throwable` was being thrown.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Coz we don't see the source of the superclass I could apologize first exception `OntNoObjectExistsException` is caught in the superclass and then `RuntimeException` is thrown. Half true.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik In the superclass exception is caught, printed (my comment #2) stacktrace, and nothing thrown else. Another Half true. Now 100% true.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the the other answer that it is very bad practice to use exceptions for flow control but to actually answer your question have you tried to catch Throwable instead of Exception?

```
catch (Throwable t) {
    // handle here.
}
```

Comment: Quote OP: "FWIW, I tried reducing to a single catch catching Throwable, and the problem persisted"

Comment: @Ben This may have been better as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You have no control over `getUserByUserId()`; however, it seems to be in the same package `com.bcbst.dsmart.api`, so **this answer assumes** (so as to move on) it is outside your responsibility within the same project, **but you have its source files**.

Could there be a mismatch between the sources of the class `getUserByUserId()` belongs to, and the compiled version that's being used at runtime?

If the `throws` statements have been modified within that class after they have been compiled, or the exceptions themselves have been changed, this could explain this apparently absurd situation of yours.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9275314/326294) on SO for more on that hypothesis.

=> Recompile everything, and redeploy.